# What is the [student-motivation] for real [engagement]?

Tags: discussion, retagging

I realize that getting the students motivated to learn the subject is often a problem. Even more so when sections of the class can become *dry*. Students who rapidly grasp some of the concepts can be especially challenging to keep motivated as well. It seems that a common technique is to get the students engaged in the class, or the subject matter, to engourage the self-motivation to keep them going when the instructor can't. Does this mean that [student-motivation](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/student-motivation) is really [engagement](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engagement)? Or, is it the other way around?

[engagement](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engagement) has 4 questions, and the following wiki excerpt:

> Engaging students in lessons using engaging rhetoric, activities, and other thing which cause or could cause student to be more focused and interested in the task at hand or the class.

[student-motivation](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/student-motivation) has 6 questions, and the following wiki excerpt:

> Questions about motivating students to study, participate, or take interest in the field of Computer Science. This tag can be used to ask questions regarding motivating students in the context of Computer Science (e.g. motivating them to self-teach or to work with other etc. as well as motivating them to study Computer Science)

Neither has a full wiki entry.

*Should they be one in the same, a single tag for both? Which one?*

Answer (score 4):

I think [engagement](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engagement) should be merged into [student-motivation](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/student-motivation). They are quite synonymous.

I doubt any question about students getting an engagement ring would arise here. (maybe in [here](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/))

So engagement as a tag of its own is confusing. [student-motivation](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/student-motivation) isn't. I suggest we make them synonyms.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of teaching, [student-engagement](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/student-engagement) is a common way to address what the wiki for [engagement](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engagement) currently describes. Part of the challenge of engaging students is motivating them to see the broader relevance of said topic, so [motivation](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motivation) does relate strongly to [student-engagement](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/student-engagement).

Engagement is likely to be a more common topic for our community since engaging students in challenging and/or abstract topics, viz. complexity analysis or the compilation process, is a common topic for any educator. They are very closely related, but since "student engagement" is a common educational phrase, it'd make more sense for our community with respect to these two tags.